# I need help finding the probability of this question.

Tags: probability

There are 3 blue blocks, 5 green blocks, 6 red blocks, and 8 yellow blocks in a bag. What is the probability that two of the red blocks can be chosen in a row? (Not putting the first block back)

So what I've done is get $\frac{6}{22}$ for the first grab. Then I got $\frac{5}{21}$ for the second grab. I multiply and get $\frac{5}{77}$. It feels wrong, can someone tell me if it's right or if not how to do it?

Comment: You got that right!

Comment: Since you are new here, [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide on how to use LaTeX to format your questions. You didn't really need it in this post, although it would have been good for the fractions, but it's a good thing to learn for the future. It's also generally good to concisely give your question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct.

You have $6$ red blocks, so the probability of selecting a red block first is $\frac{6}{22}$. Then there are only $5$ red blocks and $21$ blocks left, giving $\frac{5}{21}$. So the total probability is $$\frac{6}{22}\cdot\frac{5}{21}=\frac{5}{77}\approx.0649$$